# Framedecoder buffer corrupt at high throughput

Tags: netty

I have a simple decoder that extends FrameDecoder to decode a binary message which has an integer header field (4 bytes) that represents the length of the message body. In the decode implementation, first four bytes are read to get the length of message. And when the buffer has "length" bytes, a new buffer is created to hold the message.

This works fine when the system is at normal load. However, sometimes when the throughput is high, I am noticing that the buffer is corrupted ("length" has a very high value).

Are there any performance limitations in using FrameDecoder? Has anyone encountered this issue? Please share your thoughts on what could cause this.

**More info:** This happens mostly in cases when messageReceived is **blocked** (waiting for some operation to complete) for sometime and then resumes operation.

Are there any issues in having a blocking call in messageReceived? If so, are there any workarounds? Please help me with your advise to fix this issue.

Comment: It should work just fine. What version you use ?

Comment: What you mean with "blocked" ?

Comment: I developed a stand alone Java server to test this. It was a simple server with a decoder and handler. The decoder extends from FrameDecoder to parse the length prefixed binary message (implementation similar to IntegerHeaderFrameDecoder mentioned in javadoc).  The messageReceived function in ServerHandler was blocked for 5 minutes(with Thread.sleep). With this implementation, I noticed that the stream was corrupted (As mentioned above, length had junk value).

Comment: Well you should never block here, but anyway it should not corrupt anything. Could you open an issue at the netty github issue and include your server that reproduce this ?

Comment: messageReceived() is being called in the worker thread which processes nio selector. If it will be blocked, no more messages will be received and probably sent. You can use asynchronous queue e.g.